# AC air handler turning off when compressor comes on

Tags: hvac

Trane air handler blower works fine in manual mode with heat/cool setting off. When switched to cool position, compressor comes on but blower turns off.

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your air handler please?

Comment: Can you give us the model # and verify your LED’s are not flashing. Some models make sure the coils are cold before starting the air handler it usually only takes a couple of minutes.